# M2E Connector for kie-maven-plugin?

Tags: eclipse, maven, drools, kie

I am using BPM Suite 6 to create a git repository and shell project. I am then connecting to the git repo in my Eclipse IDE.

The Pom file created by BPM Suite web GUI includes the kie-maven-plugin. However Eclipse complains that this "Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration".

From Googling this error a bit I have come to understand that this means Eclipse does not understand when to execute this plugin during Eclipse's build process. It also seems that the 'best' way of fixing this issue is to install an m2e connector for the plugin.

Does such a connector exist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does not directly answer the question but I found a workaround in the old user forums:

http://drools-moved.46999.n3.nabble.com/rules-users-Drool-6-0-0-Final-2-question-re-kie-maven-plugin-please-td4027117.html

The workaround is to include in your pom some extra information that tells eclipse how to deal with this plugin. If I understand this correctly, this causes Eclipse to execute the plugin only when it builds the project. This is what the workaround ends up looking like:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
        <artifactId>kie-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.3-redhat-6</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>kie-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[6.0.0,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>build</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore />
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
  </build>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is known Eclipse limitation, as it is not so flexible with custom Maven goals. This is the design way eclipse m2 plugin chose to go. You can chose actions like ignore,

This is what Redhat suggests for maven usage:[Redhat guide for Maven usage for Developers](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_BRMS/6.0/html/Development_Guide/chap-Maven.html)

Alternate, you can use IntelliJ what handles this just as it is expected by Maven design for usage.